# How to left align text after a figure?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, text

I don't know why after the end of a figure the text begins with some space like this:

[image]

I used "flushleft", but with the Italian rules of grammar (babel-italian) when the text goes to head, it does it wrong because leaves some space without cutting off the word correctly

Anyone can help me ??

Thanks in advance,

Luca

```
 Text...
 \begin{figure}[H]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=7cm]{Myfig}
 \caption{Mycaption}
 \label{fig:photo}
 \end{figure}
 
 Other text....
```

and the part of "Other text" begins with the left-top corner with some space[image]

when the other lines are align to the left side correctly

Comment: would you like to share the code which created this

Comment: That looks like a fairly normal paragraph indentation. Please help us helping you: share the code which produces that output, otherwise we can only guess...

Comment: I just updated the question.

Comment: Just use \noindent before you begin the text again?

Comment: Thanks a lot man it works well !!

Comment: And if, after a figure (with the use of centering), the text begins at the center how can I fix it?

Comment: @lucaamicucci This is a different question, so ask a new question and show the code that produces the problem.

Comment: For normal paragraphs you should not use `\noindent` but decide what is your rule for  highlight paragraph changes  and set `\parskip` and `\parindent`  accordingly, in order to maintain a consistent format layout through all the document . On the other hand, the `\centering` inside  the figure cannot center anything outside this environment nor the caption (in standard classes  the single-line sort captions are centered by default with or without a previous `\centering`).